# ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 50, 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was going to make a list of 50 random numbers, one to one hundred, and take the square and square root for the numbers, and I would put them into a nice PD.Dataframe (the first list is the random numbers which are the rows and the two other lists are the columns).
My Code looks like this:

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
y = random.sample(range(1, 100), 50)
y1 = [f**2 for f in y]
y2 = [round(math.sqrt(f2)) for f2 in y]
whole = y + y1 + y2
whole2 = (np.array(whole)).reshape((50,3))
df = pd.DataFrame([whole2[:,1:]], index=whole2[:,0], columns=['Number', 'Square','Square Root'])
```

I would appreciate if some one could tell me where and how I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is a little off here.  I think np.stack is a little more intuitive here as well.  You can also remove y from the stack if you would only like the random numbers one time.

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
y = random.sample(range(1, 100), 50)
y1 = [f**2 for f in y]
y2 = [round(math.sqrt(f2)) for f2 in y]
whole = np.stack([y1, y2], axis=-1)
df = pd.DataFrame(whole, index=y, columns=['Square','Square Root'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Micheal, but I was looking for a data frame that had the rows as the random numbers, and the two columns as the square & the square root. And also I am fairly new to pandas so please tell me I have a misconception.

Comment: @Ashape can you clarify?  Do you mean the left-most number should be the random numbers?  Aren't the two columns already the square and the square root here?

Comment: No I mean I want the row names to be y, not to have three columns, if I did not specify, sorry.

Comment: Thank You So Much Micheal!, that was the answer I was looking for!